# An error occurred while loading the update

Tags: imac, monterey

So yesterday I tried to update my iMac 2017 to the Monterey version, but I received this message

"An error occurred while loading the update"

[image]

ps: image from internet

[image]

Any ideas on how i can fix that without losing my data ?

Comment: What do you mean with „image from the internet“?

Comment: I forgot to take a photo from my mac, so I used one from the internet (first image)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Recovery feature?  I had an similar issue with one of my updates and reinstalled the system using [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).  Since, thanks to APFS, the system is in its own partition it is a little safer to do this than in the past.  As an added future precaution I have moved all my really important data to an external drive (as well as having a Time Machine backup)